# How to avoid automatically running a function passed as optional argument in Python (e.g., plt.gca() from `matplotlib`)

Tags: python, matplotlib

In `Python`, is there a way not to run a function which is passed as optional argument of a function when this one is executed?

For example, in `matplotlib`, the function `matplotlib.pyplot.gca(**kwargs)` is defined as:

> Get the current Axes instance on the current figure matching the given keyword args, or create one.

So depending on whether I already have a `figure` or not, it would create a new one automatically. In the following code, I am including `plt.gca()` as optional argument of a function defined before any `figure` is created, but since I am creating my `figure` just after I don't want a useless one to be created initially, which occurs in this case (it would *not* if I defined my function after creating my `figure`):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# In this case, a useless, empty Figure is created here
def putAnnotation(mytxt, myax=plt.gca()):
    myax.annotate(mytxt, xy=(0.5,0.5))

fig, [ax0, ax1] = plt.subplots(2,1)

# If I'd define the function here, there would be no useless Figure created...
# def putAnnotation(mytxt, myax=plt.gca()):
#     myax.annotate(mytxt, xy=(0.5,0.5))

putAnnotation('Hello', myax=ax1)

plt.show()
```

Is there any way not to activate the "functionality" of the function which is passed as optional argument at the execution-time of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the default arguments are evaluated only once. This is a [common python gotcha](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) and very likely not what you want here.

To avoid that, simply use `None` as a placeholder:

```
def putAnnotation(mytxt, myax=None):
    if myax is None:
        myax = plt.gca()
    myax.annotate(mytxt, xy=(0.5,0.5))
```

If you must differentiate between `None` and not passed, you can either do some `*args, **kwargs` trickery:

```
def putAnnotation(mytxt, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        myax = args[0]
    except IndexError:
        try:
            myax = kwargs['myax']
        except KeyError:
            myax = plt.gca()
    myax.annotate(mytxt, xy=(0.5,0.5))
```

Note that this does not check for multiple values or unexpected keyword `TypeError`s.
Or you use a unambiguous marker object:

```
_putAnnotation_myax_default_marker = object()
def putAnnotation(mytxt, myax=_putAnnotation_myax_default_marker):
    if myax is _putAnnotation_myax_default_marker:
        myax = plt.gca()
    myax.annotate(mytxt, xy=(0.5,0.5))
```

Comment: Accepted thanks to the additional doc link and tip about the `not passed` case (illustrating it would be maybe even better, @Zulan? Not crucial), but thanks also to @abukaj and @Mike Müller for the same nice answer!

Comment: I added two examples on how to differentiate between None and not passed.

Answer (score 3):

The function `plt.gca()` would be called exactly once - at the function **definition**.

It may be dangerous in case of working with more than one axis.

To get the current axis it when no axis is passed as `putAnnotation()` argument, you may use:

```
def putAnnotation(mytxt, myax=None):
    if myax is None:
        myax = plt.gca()
    myax.annotate(mytxt, xy=(0.5,0.5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an new plot only when needed:

```
def putAnnotation(mytxt, myax=None):
    if myax is None:
        myax = plt.gca()
    myax.annotate(mytxt, xy=(0.5,0.5))
```